# Site to ask data visualization questions; that are not programming related

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Is there a reasonable Stack Exchange site to ask about data visualization questions, that are not related to the programming of visualization software/libraries, but rather the best way to present a certain type of data in a visualization?

For example; a question might be

"How do I best represent a timelapse heatmap of two different data sets, and the differences between the two?"

Is there any site where this would be on-topic?  If there are multiple, what is the best site to ask it on?

Comment: [Data visualization is on topic on Cross Validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) (though I don't know if your specific question is)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This question is completely on-topic on the [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) SE and the [DataScience](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/) SE, as it asks about the representation of data sets on a heat map.

You can ask about the relevance in the site's meta.

And as the comment above says, [data visualization is indeed on-topic](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) on CrossValidated. So, it is better suited there, than on the DataScience SE.

Answer (score 3):

[User Experience](https://ux.stackexchange.com/) seems to be what you are looking for. It's about Specific UX design problems which is what that seems to be, for instance the site has a [heatmaps](/questions/tagged/heatmaps) tag with [several questions](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/heatmaps).

As always be sure to check out the [help centre](https://ux.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) first. If you're still not sure even after that, you could always ask on the [site meta](https://ux.meta.stackexchange.com/) whether your question is on-topic.

Comment: I thought UX is about controls/interface design and not specific data representation?

Comment: Have a look at some of the questions and tags, it sure seems more broad than you're suggesting it is. There's some [heatmaps](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/heatmaps) questions there already.

Answer (score 3):

Graphic Design allows questions about the non-programmatic aspects of data visualizations.

[GDSE Tag: Data-Visualization](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data-visualisation)